# Jumping slides in slick slider with variable width and center mode

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using the slick slider to show an centered slider on my site.
The slider should show one item in the center and display smaller items left and right.

To do this, I'm using `centerMode` and `variableWidth`. 
The problem now is, that the slides are "jumping" after every change.

It looks good in the docs. What is my mistake?

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/vv4j3uz2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that you have two different image's heights whether its parent slide has the center class or not.

```
.slider-header .slick-slide img {height: 520px; [...]}
.slider-header .slick-slide.slick-center img {height: 600px; [...]}
```

Make them the same and your issue is gone ;)

Comment: The different heights are on purpose. I've removed the jumping by adding a fixed height to the slider. Unfortunately that's not very responsive.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I must have misread cuz I hadn't read that you wanted the left and the right images smaller.

Anyway, if you are still looking for some advices, this could solve your problem:

`.slider-header .slick-slide:not(.slick-center) img {transform: scale(0.8); height: auto; width: auto; opacity: 0.5;transition: all 300ms ease 0s;}`

Answer (score 1):

If you give the .slick-track some CSS animation transition it works well.

```
.slick-track { transition: all 0.3s ease; }
```